# Import textfile into MS Access Table on a machine without Office Professional

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm writing a tool for a user that does not run Office Professional (Office Standard).  Which means that they don't have MSAccess installed on their system. So the following code fails (called from Excel):

```
    Dim appAccess As Object
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    With appAccess
        .OpenCurrentDatabase Range("DBfile")
        .Application.Run "importmms"
        .Quit
    End With
```

Although I think this used to work (so then I'm looking for why this code is not working anymore on the Standard license machine), it's not working anymore.  So I am trying to find a solution for **importing a .csv** file into an **Access table** from **VBA in Excel** on a machine that **does not run MS Access**.

Answer (score 1):

If msaccess.exe exists in an Office 2010 Standard installation, they probably have the Access **Runtime** installed.

Users missing it can download and install it (it's free) :

[Access 2010 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910)
plus
[Service Pack 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39643)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is probably a hack, and not reliable in many circumstances. But apparently on the client's PC is msaccess.exe (whether or not that is Licensed or not.  (Perhaps someone could just confirm if msaccess.exe did in fact ship with the standard license of the Office software)

So I just ran it from the command line:

```
If FileExist("c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\msaccess.exe") Then
    Shell ("c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\msaccess.exe """ & dbpath & """ /x ImportMMS")
End If
```